# Is there a way to increment the slice method in v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

This might sound not achievable but I'm just curious if it's possible to invoke the slice method
in the v-for loop to increment the slice value when a function is invoked. It is like a LoadMore function that when you click a button it will load more data. Like if I have

```
<div v-for="(itm, index) in stockList.slice(0, 5)" :key="itm.stockId">
    ...   
</div>
<input type="button"  v-on:click="ShowMore"  />
```

**Methods:**

```
ShowMore(){
....// increment the slice in the v-for loop binding
counter = counter + 5.
this.stockList.slice(0, counter);
}
```

Something like that...Would that be achievable? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you replace the hardcoded `5` in the template with a `counter` data property that you change when the button is clicked, then yes.

Comment: You can use `stockList.slice(0, lengthItem)` instead and lengthItem is updated when user click on `Load More` for example

Comment: Decade Moon, thanks for your suggestion, I was able to make it with the help of Vuex state for the counter.

Comment: Dieu Linh  where is the lengthItem came from? Is it this one? stockList.length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div v-for="(itm, index) in stockList.slice(0, comCounter)" :key="itm.stockId">
    ...   
</div>
<input type="button"  v-on:click="ShowMore"  />
```

**Methods:**

```
ShowMore(){
....// increment the slice in the v-for loop binding
mapCredential.state.comCounter = this.comCounter + 5;
this.comCounter = mapCredential.state.comCounter;
}
```

With the help of Vuex state variable. The increment counter is working.